# Struggeling with p tag not breaking the text

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with some HTML and CSS. I have a div tag with two div children. They are floating next to each other (prop_img and prop_desc for reference later). The left one has a fixed height and width. The right one also has two children. but they are over each other (prop_text and prop_button). The top one has a h3 tag and a p tag. The bottom one has a button. The width of the entire thing has a min and max width. When I resize the window the p tag should wrap the words so that they don't go outside their parent. The problem that I have is that when the p tag has enough text that it would need more than one line it just takes the entire div tag prop_desc and puts it under prop_img. What I want it to do is wrap the words to a next line.

I have tried to use wrap-word:break-word; and word-break: break-all; I have googled but only get people that have long words and not sentences that they want to break.

```css
article {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
}

article:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.prop_img {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
}

.location {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.6;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: inherit;
}

.location p {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.prop_desc {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
}

.prop_text {
  text-align: left;
}

.prop_text h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.prop_button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  outline-style: double;
}

.detail_button {
  background-color: blue;
}

.detail_button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article>
    <div class="prop_img">
      <img src="image" height="150px" width="200px">
      <div class="location">
        <p>Location</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prop_desc">
      <div class="prop_text">
        <h3>Headline</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut l est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="prop_button">
        <input class="detail_button" type="button" name="Details" value="Details">
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle for questions like this with all the required code available, it makes it waaay easier to debug it and tell you where you went wrong. But my guess is flawed CSS since I cant see anything directly wrong with the html.

Comment: Made a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6140L388/
As you can see the text gets place under the picture not to the right of it

Comment: You know the widths of the article and prop_img. Just give prop_desc a width value of the remaining space.

Comment: @SimonHyll No need since you can create an embedded stack snippet in the question itself here

Comment: @j08691 yes but i prefer jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure I get what you mean but if you want the text at the right of the pic, just delete the float from its div, like this:

```
  .prop_desc{
     margin-left: 0.5em;
     position: relative;
     height: 150px;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the help. I had misunderstood how and what float does. It's now fixed by removing the float from .prop_desc

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed width for `article`(500px) and fixed width for `.prop_img` (200px). So why not calculate the width of `.prop_desc` as (500 - 200 - <any margins and borders of `.prop_img` and `.prop_desc`>). In your case it turns out to be 292px.

Note: you have used different units (`em` and `px`) in your code. I will recommend that you use a single unit for easier maintenance.

```css
article {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
}

article:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.prop_img {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
}

.location {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.6;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: inherit;
}

.location p {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.prop_desc {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 292px;
}

.prop_text {
  text-align: left;
}

.prop_text h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.prop_button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  outline-style: double;
}

.detail_button {
  background-color: blue;
}

.detail_button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article>
    <div class="prop_img">
      <img src="image" height="150px" width="200px">
      <div class="location">
        <p>Location</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prop_desc">
      <div class="prop_text">
        <h3>Headline</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut l est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="prop_button">
        <input class="detail_button" type="button" name="Details" value="Details">
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the help. I had misunderstood how and what float does. I fixed it by removing float from .prop_desc. What I see now that is missing from my question is that the width of the article tag is resizable depending on the width of the browser. In the html file that i'm creating I have multiple article tags after each other, but since it was inside the article tag I had problems I only included that in my question, but forgot to add that the width was resizable

Answer (score 0):

You should make prop_desc float right instead of left and use auto height, i think thats what you want.

Or

You can use overflow-y scrolling to make it scrollable when it is more than 150 px in size.

Also, try to start using cm or in instead of px, they give you better cross browser results.

Comment: thank you for the help. I had misunderstood how and what float does. I fixed it by removing float from .prop_desc.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)